# Two loggers for two separate python files

Tags: python, logging

I have two file `entrypoint.py` and `op_helper.py` that I am trying to send each scripts logs to different log files (`webhook.log` & `op.log`). I set up my `logger.py` file with two different log classes.

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler

class Logger:
    def create_timed_rotating_log(self, path):
        logger = logging.getLogger("Rotating Log")

        logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        
        handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(path,
                                        when="d",
                                        interval=1,
                                        backupCount=7)

        formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt='%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
                                  datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        
        logger.addHandler(handler)
        return logger
class WebhookLogger:
    def create_timed_rotating_log(self, path):
        logger = logging.getLogger("Rotating Log")

        logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        
        handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(path,
                                        when="d",
                                        interval=1,
                                        backupCount=7)

        formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt='%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
                                  datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        
        logger.addHandler(handler)
        return logger


today = datetime.today()
month = today.strftime("%B")

logger = Logger().create_timed_rotating_log(f'./{month + str(today.year)}Logger.log')
webhook_logger = WebhookLogger().create_timed_rotating_log(f'./{month + str(today.year)}WebhookLogger.log')
```

In my `entrypoint.py` script:

```
from logger import webhook_logger

webhook_logger.info("Something to log")
```

And in my `op_helper.py` script:

```
from logger import logger

logger.info("Something else to log")
```

But when I run the script, both log statements are logged to both log files.

```
2021-10-15 14:17:51 INFO Something to log
2021-10-15 14:17:51 INFO Something else to log
```

Can anyone explain to me what's going on here, and possibly, what I'm doing incorrectly?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an excerpt from the documentation for *logging* (the bold is mine):

> logging.getLogger(name=None)

> Return a logger with the specified name or, if name is None, return a logger which is the root logger of the hierarchy. If specified, the name is typically a dot-separated hierarchical name like ‘a’, ‘a.b’ or ‘a.b.c.d’. Choice of these names is entirely up to the developer who is using logging.

> **All calls to this function with a given name return the same logger instance.** This means that logger instances never need to be passed between different parts of an application.

...
The solution, therefore, is to assign a different name to your second logger.

EDIT:
Keep in mind, however, that, as you can see, calling getLogger either creates a new instance, if one under the given name doesn't exist, or returns an already existing instance. Therefore every following instruction will only modify an existing logger. If your intention is to use your classes to create multiple instances of one logger type, that approach will not work. Right now, they both do exactly the same thing, so there's not really a need for two separate classes either. As you can see, *logging* doesn't lend itself well to being used with an object-oriented approach, because the objects are already instanced elsewhere and can be accessed as "global" objects. But this is all just a side note.

Comment: Correct, all you have to do is change the logging.getLogger(<name>). Thank you!